# How can I write an if statement into class?

Tags: php

I have a class like this:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    // I need to put a if() in here

    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    // there is some other methods in here

}
```

As I've commented in the code above (`// I need to put a if() in here`), I need to compare something in there and use the result as `$redirectTo` variable's value.

But PHP doesn't let me to do that. I mean, I want something like this:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    if ( Lang::getLocale() == 'en' ){
        $lang = '/en';
    } else {
        $lang = '/fa';
    }

    protected $redirectTo = '/home'.$lang;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    // there is some other methods in here

}
```

As I said, php doesn't let me to do this ^. How can I do that?

---

**EDIT:** I cannot put that if statement into `__construct()` method. Because `setLocale()` hasn't been set yet and `getLocale()` always return default language *(which is `fa`)*. Anyway I need to put that if statement out of `__construct()`. Any suggestion?

Comment: Add your code to `__construct`

Comment: if ( Lang::getLocale() == 'en' ) here you are using another class lang. But there is no reference of that here in the code. That may be the problem. If condition will be used inside a class' function

Comment: As you see, `__construct()` is **under** `$redirectTo` variable .. So I cannot use `$lang` as `$redirectTo` value if I write that condition into `__construct()`.

Comment: put that inside construct! or just modified the object attributes inside construct function

Comment: If you can write a if statement there would be very inconsistent. How about declaring a private variable inside the class and put the if statement inside the `__construct()`

Comment: You can't do this in that way . You should add this to __construct function or any other yours defined function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your logics to constructor:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    protected $redirectTo;

    public function __construct()
    {
        if ( Lang::getLocale() == 'en' ){
            $lang = '/en';
        } else {
            $lang = '/fa';
        }
        $this->redirectTo = '/home'.$lang;

        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    // there is some other methods in here

}
```

**Update:**

Class code is just a **definition of a class**. It is not executed in any way. Only class methods can be executed when you explicitly call to them.

Class **can't have** anything except properties, constants or methods.

If you need to perform some actions - create class method. There's **NO OTHER WAY**.

If you need to set `$this->redirectTo` after call of `setLocale()` then either create instance of class after this call:

```
Lang::setLocale();
$ac = new AuthController();
```

Or create a special method in your class which checks and sets `$this->redirectTo`:

```
$ac = new AuthController();
Lang::setLocale();
$ac->setRedirectTo();
```

Where `setRedirectTo()` is something like:

```
public function setRedirectTo()
{
    if ( Lang::getLocale() == 'en' ){
        $lang = '/en';
    } else {
        $lang = '/fa';
    }
    $this->redirectTo = '/home'.$lang;
}
```

Comment: if you can store locale value into session, then in constructor we can check with session value, at that time it will work well

Answer (score 4):

you can try this one:

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

protected $lang='';
protected $redirectTo='';


    public function __construct()
    {
    if ( Lang::getLocale() == 'en' ){
        $this->$lang = '/en';
    } else {
        $this->$lang = '/fa';
    }

    $this->$redirectTo= '/home'.$lang;

        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    // there is some other methods in here

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow this bellow :

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    protected $redirectTo;
    protected $lang;

    public function __construct()
    {
        if ( Lang::getLocale() == 'en' ){
            $this->lang = '/en';
        } else {
            $this->lang = '/fa';
        }
        $this->redirectTo = '/home'.$this->lang;

        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    // there is some other methods in here

}
```